# Unable to set Pivot Field to Hidden

Tags: vba, excel

Hopefully this will be an easy one, but I can't find the answer to this particular scenario. I'm using the following code to hide and unhide pivot fields based on user selections. The variable `fieldShow` is a boolean that is true if the user wants to see that particular field, while `fieldLastVal` is a boolean that tells whether that field is currently showing or not.

```
If fieldShow <> fieldLastVal Then
    If fieldShow Then
        With pt.PivotFields(fieldName)
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Function = xlSum
        End With
    Else
        pt.PivotFields(fieldName).Orientation = xlHidden
    End If
End If
fieldLastVal = fieldShow
```

The issue is on the line to hide the pivot field. The thing is, the code executes just fine. No errors, no nothing. However, it never actually hides the pivot field. It's still there as if nothing happened. I stepped through the code, and that line definitely executes, it just has no effect whatsoever on the pivot table, and I don't understand why.

The line that sets a pivot field's orientation to `xlDataField` has the desired effect. I'm not really sure what's happening here.

Anythoughts?

Comment: This line of code seems like it should work, assuming `fieldName` is valid. If it wasn't valid you'd get an error, unless you've got and `On Error Resume Next` somewhere upstream. You don't do you?

Comment: Nope. No `On Error` statement. And `fieldName` is definitely valid, because the same `fieldName` variable is working just fine on the `...Orientation = xlDataField` statement. Hence my confusion.

Comment: I have one other thought. Changing a pivot field's `Orientation` to `xlDataField` changes its name, e.g., from "My Data" to "Count of My Data". So if you are trying to set a data field to hidden you might actually be acting on the other one.

Comment: That is EXACTLY the issue. I knew it was going to be some silly little thing like that I was overlooking. If you want to put your explanation down below as an answer to the question I'll accept it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing a pivot field's `Orientation` to `xlDataField` changes its name, e.g., from "My Data" to "Count of My Data". So if you are trying to set "Count of My Data" to hidden you might actually be acting on "My Data."